# How to format cheerio selector for a nested div?

Tags: html, css-selectors, cheerio

I need some help scraping a website using [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org):

https://www.keepandshare.com/calendar/mobile.php?i=1940971&do=n

The text I want to scrape is right after the `<p>`. I want to fetch the last occurrence of this text from within the `calendar_one_line_text` div.

```html
<div class="calendar_one_line_text">
    <p>Cedar 3,044 gr/m3 High, Grass 27 gr/m3 High, Trees 27 gr/m3 Medium, Molds Low</p>
</div>
```

How would you structure your selector to return this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we need to focus on here is the Selectors portion of the documentation for Cheerio.

```
$( selector, [context], [root] )
```

selector searches within the context scope which searches within the root scope. selector and context can be a string expression, DOM Element, array of DOM elements, or cheerio object. root is typically the HTML document string.

This selector method is the starting point for traversing and manipulating the document. Like jQuery, it's the primary method for selecting elements in the document, but unlike jQuery it's built on top of the CSSSelect library, which implements most of the Sizzle selectors.

With this information and looking at the HTML you've provided, we can come to the conclusion of the selectors that we need! We have a div with a class of `.calendar_one_line_text` and within that we have the `p` tag.

So, on the idea of selector, we select something specific and then we can continue to drill down into something more specific. Start at `.calendar_one_line_text` and then grab the `p` tag found within it.

`$('.calendar_one_line_text p').text()`

For a full example, you can see where I implemented the above text.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`<div class="calendar_one_line_text">
<p>Cedar 3,044 gr/m3 High, Grass 27 gr/m3 High, Trees 27 gr/m3 Medium, Molds Low</p>
</div>`);
const wordsAfterP = $('.calendar_one_line_text p').text()
console.log(wordsAfterP)
```

If you're looking to get the last occurrence, you can convert `wordsAfterP` to an array and then grab the last elements data

```
const wordsAfterP = $('.calendar_one_line_text p').toArray()
console.log(wordsAfterP[wordsAfterP.length - 1].firstChild.data)
```

Comment: Thank you @Caleb Mabry but there are multiple instances of `.calendar_one_line_text` on the page. How do I select the last one?  For reference the entire page is located here:

https://www.keepandshare.com/calendar/mobile.php?i=1940971&do=n

Comment: I am able to log things like `.mobile_content` which is a top-level div class. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to grab the final `.calendar_one_line_text` on the page, which is all I need for this project...

Comment: @spidey We can convert it to an array using `const wordsAfterP = $('.calendar_one_line_text p').toArray()` and then grabbing the last `Node` and getting the data from it
`wordsAfterP[wordsAfterP.length - 1].firstChild.data`

Comment: Doesn't work. The code returns an empty array.

`{"error":"Internal Server Error! Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined"}`

There's something wrong with the selector.  It's not creating an array from all the elements with class `.calendar_one_line_text`.

Comment: I think I have spotted the problem. Trying to fetch the URL with command line tools such as wget, curl, or cheerio does not retrieve all the data. It looks like that data that I want only loads in a web browser.  I tried passing in a user agent but that didn't work either...

Comment: You will probably have to use a headless browser or something similar to get all of the data

Comment: @spidey This solution should work [I've posted it on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aV1qm9eL). It's all in Javascript and uses Puppeteer.

Comment: I tried to deploy it onto Google Cloud functions but couldn't get it working.  I think the problem might lie on the Google side.  Or it might be a me thing.  Anyway thank you for taking the time to help; I'll award you the solution points.

Comment: If you find a way to get Puppeteer to work on Google Cloud functions or get this working, please update!

Comment: I may try again later. Unfortunately I have spent way too much time on this and am not even sure Puppeteer works on GCP.  Most of the blog posts and tutorials I found are either out of date or inaccurate. The reality of server less functions is a lot more difficult than the cloud providers would have you believe...

Comment: Ok I was able to refactor this a bit to come up with a working solution.  Here is the gist URL with code that works on google cloud functions: